# Why is the default axis of 3d cursor rotated by around 45 degree in Blender?

Tags: 3d-cursor, blenderkit

When I shift + right click anywhere in the viewport, the 3d cursor will be placed there. When i rotate the screen I can see that the 3d cursor is rotated by around 45 degree. It is not in perpendicular orientation. So when I import models using blenderkit addon, all the imported models will come rotated due to the rotated 3d cursor. The models should ideally be inserted normally and straight, not rotated 45 degrees.

Please provide me the answer to this, since I am stuck here.

Thank you,
Kris

Answer (score 2):

Check your "N" properties panel, View tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After I change all these 3 values of rotation to 0, and then again click shift+right click elsewhere on the screen, the values will again change automatically. It seems it has made these values as default. How do I make the rotation values as 0 by default.

Comment: What happens with the shortcut Shift C?

Comment: @joshsanfelici Shift+C resets the 3D cursor's rotation but also its location to the world origin. If you want to keep the cursor where it is, Shift+C is no option.

Comment: You can press *backspace* while hovering on the rotation to set it to 0,0,0

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, but using the *3D Cursor Tool* you can change the default orientation when positioning the *3D Cursor*.

So, if you set *Oritentation* to *Transform* for example, it uses the orientation which is set for transforming. If this orientation is set to *Global*, then the *3D Cursor* will be placed rotated like the world's orientation axis.

If you want the *3D Cursor* to be aligned to the face of another object, you can set *Orientation* > *Geometry*.

//EDIT: I'm not quite sure if I understood the question correctly: do you want the cursor to be at the world's center and without rotation, or place it somewhere in the view without changing the rotation? For resetting rotation **and** location you can simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

[image: 3d cursor]

Comment: Transform works perfectly. Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking at.

Comment: @KrisM As you commented on the other answer, _Geometry_ is also possible if perhaps you want to place objects not aligned to the world's orientation but some face of another object. Added that to my answer for completeness' sake.

Comment: @KrisM Would you mind accepting one of those answers here? ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you place the 3d cursor with your mouse(Shift+RMB or with Cursor Tool) it gets aligned to your current view, that you are using for the operation. You could use the Snap menu(Shift+S)

[image]

to snap the cursor to something retaining its previous orientation or you could use orthographic views when placing your cursor in addition to choosing its orientation in the n panel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I understand how 3d cursor works in Blender better. We cannot always keep thee 3d cursor perpendicular since it will align to the view in which we are working. The solution for importing blenderkit objects will be that, we must select the cursor tool from the left vertical panel, then select orientation as geometry, and click on any floor surface. Then when you import the model it will be perpendicular to the floor and look proper. Or as josh sanfelici said, we can change the values from n panel.

Comment: @KrisM I know of course that you can change the values, but I thought that would be to uncomfortable to do manually if you only want to reset to 0.